# Accidentally deleted perforce label. How to restore?

Tags: label, perforce

Today I accidentally deleted label in perforce. Is there any way to get this label back? Note that I don't want to replace file with revision that was labelled. I just want a label back so that in future somebody can get the files contained within it. I use Perforce Visual Client (Windows) and not command line.

Answer (score 0):

Was it a static label or an automatic label?

If it was an automatic label, you can probably recover it from your spec depot (assuming you had a spec depot).

Whether it was a static label or an automatic label, you can probably recover it from your journal, or from your most recent checkpoint, if the checkpoint was taken after you made the label.

Either way, you'll need a bit of help from Perforce Technical Support, so you should contact them.